# Not able to pass a function as a prop to child in my react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have my main App.js where i am only doing some routing and settings states in the constructor and looks like this.

```
  class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.state= {
        modalstuffshown: false,
        modalitems: null,
      }
    this.newalerter = this.newalerter.bind(this);
  } 
   newalerter() {
     Alert.alert("hey")
 }     

  const MainScreenPage = () => (
   <View>
     <TopMovies />
   </View>
  )

  const SearchPage = () => (
   <View>
    <SearchPageComp 
     newalerter={this.newalerter}
   />
  </View>
  )

  export const RootTabs = TabNavigator({
    MSPage: {
    screen: MainScreenPage,
    },
  SPage: {
    screen: SearchPage,
    },
  })

  export default RootTabs;
```

And I am trying to call the function `newalerter` which should alert with "hey" inside my `SearchPageComp` after passing it as props gives an error.

```
  <Button onPress={()=>{this.props.newalerter()}} title="click here" />
```

But i get an error saying `undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this3.props.newalerter()')`

Is it because I am not exporting App class as default by doing

```
  export default class RandomShakePage extends React.Component {
```

I am already exporting the RootTabs as default and it says I can only export one per module.

Comment: by the looks of things, your `newalerter` definition doesn't take an argument

Comment: Sorry, meant to not do that for this demo. I removed the argument so its just `<Button onPress={()=>{this.props.newalerter()}} title="click here" />` which should send alert, but its not and getting error `undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this3.props.newalerter()')`

Comment: Not sure if you copied that correctly, your current code causes parsing errors because you have `const` in your class. Also your tabNavigator is missing a curly bracket somewhere. Please fix so we can properly help.